# Background color slide transition

Tags: html, css

i have build this solution but i want this with background-color not with background-image. How is this possible?

```
#contentrightbox {
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;

    display:block;
    background:url(http://s7.directupload.net/images/140101/648rkjkd.gif);

    -webkit-transition: background-position 100ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position 100ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-position 100ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-position 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background-position 100ms ease-in-out; 
}

#contentrightbox:hover {
    background-position:0px -58px;   
}
```

**SOLUTION: [Final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M927W/5/)**

Comment: Maybe, you could play with "background: linear-gradient( black 50%, white 50% );" and update the "50%" parameter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M927W/4/ I've changed this but I don't expect how you get your image to change color?

Comment: This works BUT i want to solve it with background-color not with background-image

Comment: I think you can not get the same effect by working with background-color property. The transition will be a fade between two colors, not a translation as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should add a `span` element with your second background color and change its `top` position. I edited your Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/M927W/1/. Is this what you wanted to do?

You could also avoid using a `span` element with pseudo-elements.

Comment: the problem is what when i but a logo or a text over it's not working

Comment: Right. I didn't understand you wanted to put a text. Actually I have done it on a website I developed a while ago. I used two spans with two different classes.
You can check it out here (main menu) : http://gotelltheeskimo.com/. But maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: That's exactly what i want!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css by using a gradient

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, white 50%);
```

for a demo see: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M927W/2/)

Comment: That's possible but not the way i want